# Why is 3<–1 in code?

Tags: c++

Take a look at the following code:

```
int start = 3;

vector<int> data;
data.push_back(0);
data.push_back(0);

for (int i=start; i<data.size()-start; i++)
    printf("In...\n");
```

When running the above code, it will run `printf("In...\n");` infinitely. Although based on the condition `(3<-1)` of the for loop, it should never do this. Weird, huh?

To avoid this, you have to compute the long condition equation first, like:

```
… …

int end = data.size()-start;
for (int i=start; i<end; i++)
    printf("In...\n");
```

Why this happens?

Comment: Turn on/up your compiler warnings and the answer should be in front of you.

Comment: If you print `data.size()-start` inside your `for` loop you will notice a negative value :) `2-3 = -1` and `i = 3`, so it will take a while for 3 to become negative

Comment: @nrathaus No `data.size()-start` is `unsigned`, and that is the problem.

Comment: @chris no warnings showed.

Comment: Use W4 for VisualStudio and -Wall for GCC. You signed/unsigned mismatch in data.size()-start.

Answer (score 6):

size() returns an unsigned value (of type size_t) which causes the expression on the right of the comparison to be promoted to unsigned which then makes the comparison unsigned.

So there are no negative numbers where you think there are, just very large positive ones.

As other people have said, most compilers will warn you about this if you turn up the warning level, and c++ is not a language that can safely be used at a low warning level.

Comment: I suspect the people who know what 'UB' is don't need help with this stuff.... ;-)

Comment: @datenwolf No. Not for unsigned. It's well-defined.

Comment: @BlueMoon: Also if I have a negative signed integer that's casted to an unsigned int?

Comment: @datenwolf There's no UB in the comparison part but UB happens when `i` overflows INT_MAX.. size_t is usually unsigned int or unsigned long. The negative number is converted into an unsigned value using reduction modulo rule (\*_MAX + 1 -3) and where `i` (as in `i<...`) is converted to unsigned value and then then comparison happens.