# Access violation writing location when modifying char *

Tags: c++

I have the following simple code:

```
char *a = "aaaa";
*a = 'b'; // error here: access violation writing location
```

Can anyone explain the reason of getting this error? Does it mean I cannot edit `a` after it's been initialised?

Comment: What do you mean "any more"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Edit `a` later.

Comment: After it's been initialised, then.

Comment: I found a better discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9631091/3126987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literals are immutable. You are not allowed to attempt to modify them.

```
char* a = "aaaa";         // deprecated!
*a = 'b';                 // unsafe & undefined
```

Your compiler *should* be warning you that, actually, your code should read:

```
const char* a = "aaaa";   // OK
*a = 'b';                 // can't compile
```

The `const` prevents it from even compiling.

<strike>I notice that the problem in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20728649/560648) was *also* caused by not heeding warnings (and/or having them switched off). **Read your compiler's warnings.**</strike>

It looks like Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 doesn't emit any warning, though, which is *really* sad.

Anyway, if you want to copy the string literal's contents into a local copy:

```
char a[] = "aaaa";        // OK: a copy
*a = 'b';                 // OK
```

Comment: I tested it under VS, which gives no warnings. PS: it seems I don't disable warnings.

Comment: @tommyhu: To be fair to you, I can't seem to get a warning for this on VS2012 at any warning level. Stupid thing.